# AttributeError: 'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'addition'

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

Im having some issues getting a very simple unittest working with python/flask. Ive tried following the concept from *flaskr* and *test_flasker.py* but it throws an error which I cant find much information about:

> AttributeError: 'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'addition'

One of the 2 tests I have works. The `self.app.get('/')` does indeed return "Hello World" and this test passes. But the "addition" test can not seem to be found at all.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask
payment_app = Flask(__name__)

@payment_app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'

def addition(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #remove debug=True when running in production
    payment_app.debug = True
    payment_app.run()
```

My test code:

```
import os
import sys
from payment_app import *
import unittest

class PaymentTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass 

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass 

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = payment_app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass 

    def test_init(self):
        result = self.app.get('/')
        print result.data
        self.assertEqual(result.data, "Hello World") 

    def test_addition(self):
        result = self.app.addition(2, 5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `addition(a, b)` is not a member of your Flask `app` object, but of your *payment_app.py* file. Therefore, calling `self.app.addition(2, 5)` fails.

Change your test case to `addition(2, 5)` and everything will work:

```
class PaymentTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # some parts missing...
    def test_addition(self):
        result = addition(2, 5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 7)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks, it was driving me nuts! Since payment_app.py holds the addition(a, b) function I was under the impression that it than was accessible. Especially since I do `from payment_app import *` and since the other testcase also uses the app object via `self.app.get('/')`. I guess my question is; what is "my Flask app object"?

Comment: Your Flask app object is `payment_app`, being created using `payment_app = Flask(__name__)`. However, this is different from your source file, even if it was named the same. `from payment_app import *` refers to the file `payment_app.py`, not to your Flask app object